# Performance of mysqldbcopy for large databases

Tags: mysql, database

I am having a huge amount of problems moving a large mysql database and would love to know anyones experience with such.

Situation:
Server 1 is housing the Mysql database. Size: 3TB

Attempts to move it:
1. Mysqldump does NOT work. It simply takes too long (I waited 3 days and got a ~100 gig sql file and it didn't seem like it was going to finish).
2. Attempts to copy directly the data directory, but ensuring it works and is consistent is a very difficult for me, and this manual process seems to be risky.
3. Which lead me to mysqldbcopy

I found the mysqldbcopy command and is wondering if anyone knows the perforamnce and how it works internally. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try Percona Xtrabackup? https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.3/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information? Do you mean to say, your set up has only one server with all the data?

If its a MyISAM table copy the files will work. I have tried this.

Have you considered setting up a slave DB, but this would require work like enabling replication logs etc. (This won't be too much work)

I once remember in a master slave db set up doing something like Load data from master, for the slave and that the master had hundreds of millions of rows.

> *If you can setup master-slave db setup, you might be able to continue to use the existing db while the Slave instance catches up, if this
>   option is available.*

This might be a good example of master slave replication, to look at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

I have never played with mysqldbcopy, but I would love to know more.